# Matlab is operating oddly on debugging: keyboard or break points

Tags: matlab

I execute the following code and variable:"i" is always "1" on the "keyboard".
If I use break points... same result.
If I let the code run without "breakPoints" or "keyboard"... the "disp(i)" yields: 1..10 as expected!  Not sure why this is happening with debugging?

```
function LoopMe()
for i = 1:10
    disp(i)
    keyboard
end
```

MATLAB Version: 9.3.0.713579 (R2017b)

Windows 10 home

Comment: What version, OS, etc?  Cannot reproduce on 2016a or 2017a...

Comment: I also can't reproduce it on 2017a, it works fine, once I press "continue" button, i gives the next value.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either.  I'm also on R2016b.  I simply push F5 / Continue at each iteration and the value of `i` increases from 1 up to 10 as expected.

Comment: Missing an `end`?

Comment: Do you see `i` being displayed as `1` at each iteration? or are you seeing its value in the workspace? I doubt that you're never coming out of the pause that you make the MATLAB take with the `keyboard` command at the 1st iteration. What do you do once the keyboard command is executed? What do you enter in the command window? or what else do you do?

Comment: I press return and it should do the next iteration... ya... always "1".   I have an older version of Matlab that yields correctly... it increments

Comment: None of us can reproduce your issue. Suggest you contact MathWorks.

Comment: I will be contacting them... in the mean time I just skipped matlab and writing and looking at data results in c++